# CentOS 7 Apachect1 Removing a Virtual Host

Tags: linux, apache, centos, virtualhost

**[SOLVED]**

I have a CentOS 7 VPS running Apachect1 and I have just finished a project that required me to create multiple subdomains. Now that I am done I do not need them so I want to go back and clean up a bit.

I had originally created the files

```
/etc/httpd/sites-available/site1.domain.com.conf
/etc/httpd/sites-available/site2.domain.com.conf
/etc/httpd/sites-available/site(...).domain.com.conf
```

and

```
/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/site1.domain.com.conf
/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/site2.domain.com.conf
/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/site(...).domain.com.conf
```

They were working and everything and all I thought I had to do to remove these domains were to delete those files and restart apache. I did this but I can still access these websites. Any idea?

I ran these commands:

```
# apachectl restart
# systemctl restart named.service
# systemctl start named
# systemctl enable named
# systemct1 status httpd.service
```

I have even restarted my server but nothing. Sorry if I missed anything obvious, I am still new to Linux. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

there are several things you can do.

the first thing is to verify **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** to make sure how VIRTUAL HOSTS are defined in you file and if there are declared there.
[Centos httpd config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2eCE.gif)

If there are no VIRTUAL HOST THERE. you will need to make sure that those files do not exist

```
/etc/httpd/sites-available/site1.domain.com.conf
/etc/httpd/sites-available/site2.domain.com.conf
/etc/httpd/sites-available/site(...).domain.com.conf
```

You could also try this commands

```
service httpd stop   (to stop service)
service httpd start (to start service)
```

Let me know if this works :)

Comment: Would the line in **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** look something like this if they were not defined:

`IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf`

`IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`

Comment: Also, I did do those two httpd start and stop commands and the site is still accessible.

Comment: just to make sure, are you accesing each site site1.domain.com site2.domain.com site3.domain.com  ? is every sub-domain in a different folder ?  ex /var/www/html/site1  /var/www/html/site2.....

Comment: yes. For example, I removed the files, `/etc/httpd/sites-available/site1.domain.com.conf` file, and `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/site1.domain.com.conf`. I did not remove the content in `/var/www/html/site1`. That folder and all of its content still exist. Each subdomain is in a different folder. i.e. `/var/www/html/site1`, `/var/www/html/site2`, `/var/www/html/site3`

Comment: I have removed virtual hosts (domains/ subdomains) before and I don't remember it being this difficult.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

So I figured out how to work around this. I am not sure why but the issue was, anytime I went to a non existing subdomain I would get redirected to `/var/www/SubdomainA/index.php`

The way I worked around this was I went to each of my subdomains and added a rewrite condition in the .htaccess file that said, if the subdomain is not the specified subdomain, then send it to the main site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|SubdomainA)\.example\.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Hopefully this will help someone at some point.